# Merging multiple .npz files into single .npz file

Tags: python, list, numpy, npz-file

I have multiple .npz files in folder with same nature, I want to append all of my .npz files into a single .npz file present in a given folder

I have tried below code to achieve so, but it seems its not appending multiple .npz files to single npz file.
Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
file_list = ['image-embeddings\img-emb-1.npz', 'image-embeddings\img-emb-2.npz']
data_all = [np.load(fname) for fname in file_list]
merged_data = {}
for data in data_all:
   [merged_data.update({k: v}) for k, v in data.items()]
np.savez('new_file.npz', **merged_data)
```

Where img-emb-1.npz has different value and img-emb-2.npz has different value

Comment: Does your operating system have an archive tool?

Comment: I am trying to merge image-embeddings\img-emb-1.npz & image-embeddings\img-emb-2.npz into single new_file.npz file, both npz files have same structure but with different data.

Comment: So `data.keys()` are the same for both? Then your code just writes the 2nd archive's values to the new archive? What is it supposed to with duplicate keys/names?  I believe an archive tool would ask whether you want to overwrite, or change names in the case of duplicates. An npz contains npy files with names taken from the dict.

Comment: I think we need a small example - create 2 `npz` with actual data, and show the desired merged `npz`.

Comment: With the default windows10 archive, I can extract the `npy` files from a `file.zip` to a directory.  If I try to extract duplicates into a directory it asks if I want to overwrite, or skip.  I can't test my Linux tools at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following to construct `merged_data`:

```py
arrays_read = dict(
    chain.from_iterable(np.load(file(arr_name)).items() for arr_name in arrays.keys())
)
```

Full example:

```py
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

file = lambda name: f"arrays/{name}.npz"

# Create data
arrays = {f"arr{i:02d}": np.random.randn(10, 20) for i in range(10)}

# Save data in separate files
for arr_name, arr in arrays.items():
    np.savez(file(arr_name), **{arr_name: arr})

# Read all files into a dict
arrays_read = dict(
    chain.from_iterable(np.load(file(arr_name)).items() for arr_name in arrays.keys())
)

# Save into a single file
np.savez(file("arrays"), **arrays_read)

# Load to compare
arrays_read_single = dict(np.load(file("arrays")).items())

assert arrays_read.keys() == arrays_read_single.keys()
for k in arrays_read.keys():
    assert np.array_equal(arrays_read[k], arrays_read_single[k])
```

Comment: You are putting each array into a separate `npz` file, one array per file.  You could just as well have used `np.save` and written separate `npy` files.  I think the OP has several arrays with duplicate array names.

Comment: Yes maybe, I made a guess, without further indication from OP for reproducibility ...